# Javascript HTMLDOM appendChild results in DOM exception 8

Tags: javascript, exception, appendchild, dom

I have written the following code

```
function byId(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}
function addElm(root,elm) {
  document.createElement(elm);
  if(!root) {
      root = document;
  }
  root.appendChild(elm);
  return elm;
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function() {
  var elm = byId('myExistingElmId');
  addElm(elm,'span');
},false);
```

The element having id "myExistingElmId" is there in my document.
The line

```
root.appendChild(elm);
```

is giving me the following error in console

```
Uncaught error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8
```

Why is this happening..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `addElm` function is wrong - you're discarding the result of `document.createElement`.

It should be:

```
function addElm(root, type) {
  var elm = document.createElement(type);
  if(!root) {
      root = document.body;
  }
  root.appendChild(elm);
  return elm;
}
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/wAuvJ/

[@Ethan is also correct that it should be `document.body`, but that's incidental to the actual error you were seeing as you weren't exercising that code path]

Comment: oMG...it is my mistake...i didn't save the result..Oops

Answer (score 3):

`document` is not a DOM element, `document.body` is. And as @Alnitak said, you lost the result of `document.createElement`. This code should be work:

```
function addElm(root,elm) {
    var elm = document.createElement(elm);
    if(!root) {
        root = document.body;
    }
    root.appendChild(elm);
    return elm;
}
```

Comment: ok..but i'm passing document.getElementById('myExistingElmId')  as <root> to addElm which is a DOM element...right?

Comment: @JinuJD yes, but you lost the result of `document.createElement` at the same time.